# Faker is producing duplicate data when used in factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm trying to populate some fake data into a factory using the Faker gem:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.first_name Faker::Name::first_name
  user.last_name Faker::Name::last_name
  user.sequence(:email) {|n| "user#{n}@blow.com" }
end
```

However while I expect this to produce users who have different first_name and last_names, each one is the same:

```
>> Factory(:user)
=> #<User id: 16, email: "user7@blow.com", created_at: "2011-03-18 18:29:33",     
updated_at: "2011-03-18 18:29:33", first_name: "Bailey", last_name: "Durgan">
>> Factory(:user)
=> #<User id: 17, email: "user8@blow.com", created_at: "2011-03-18 18:29:39", 
updated_at: "2011-03-18 18:29:39", first_name: "Bailey", last_name: "Durgan">
```

How can I get the Faker gem to generate new names for each users and not just reuse the original ones?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried using something like `user.sequence(:first_name} {|n| Faker::Name::first_name}`? FactoryGirl is likely just evaluating your Faker call when it loads your "fixtures". Using the `sequence param,&block` method should prevent that.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.first_name { Faker::Name::first_name }
  user.last_name { Faker::Name::last_name }
  user.sequence(:email) {|n| "user#{n}@blow.com" }
end
```

Try putting brackets around the fakers.  see [this link](http://objectliteral.blogspot.com/2009/07/make-faker-work-with-factory-girl.html)

Comment: I love stackoverflow so much - thank you Will, you saved my bacon

Comment: Why, why, why?  What is going on here?

Comment: because of "lazy attribute", see: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#lazy-attributes

Comment: Sadly this doesn't always work.  This basically just gets a new random faker object, however because of RNG, there is still a chance this fails.

Comment: Aaaaaaand this is why writing Rails apps is only possible with Stack Overflow.  Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to fix RNG?

Answer (score 46):

Note that Faker may still be providing duplicate data due to the limited amount of fake data available.

For simple testing purposes and to get by uniqueness validations, I've used the following:

```
sequence(:first_name) {|n| Faker::Name::first_name + " (#{n})"}
sequence(:last_name) {|n| Faker::Name::last_name + " (#{n})"}
```

Comment: This answer deserves more upvotes. It's likely to happen when your test creates lot of instances.

Comment: Yup, I agree with Enrico. +1

Comment: Nice idea, but adding parenthesis can break the rest if you use first name and last name to generate emails, or you have validations on the format (don't know of any name that has parenthesis :P).

Answer (score 18):

For the sake of preserving the correct answer, here it is translocated from the blog, I take no credit for the answer.

> If you use the code below, faker will not churn out unique names

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.first_name Faker::Name.first_name
  u.last_name Faker::Name.last_name
end
```

> However putting curly braces around faker makes it work!

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
  u.last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
end
```

To explain why, the first example is producing the same names.  It's only evaluating once.  The second example evaluates every time the factory is used.

This is due to the `{}` providing lazy evaluation.  Essentially they are providing a proc/lambda with the Faker call as their return value.

Comment: Thank you for posting this. I couldn't figure out why Faker wasn't able to generate random data and it seemed like every example I came across showed how to use sequencing which seemed odd to me. I wanted to use Faker so each record is random, not sequenced. Just adding braces around my Faker calls solved the problem. Simple and elegant!

Answer (score 5):

A (less efficient) alternative to using sequences when you have a uniqueness validation on an attribute is to check whether a proposed value already exists and keep trying new ones until it's unique:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    name do
      loop do
        possible_name = Faker::Company.name
        break possible_name unless Company.exists?(name: possible_name)
      end
    end
  end
end
```