# ArgumentError:wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

So how we resolve the error in initialize function,Which thing need to be done to remove this error

> Here is the Factories/user.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do |u|
    u.first_name Faker::Name.first_name
    u.last_name Faker::Name.last_name
    u.email Faker::Internet.email
    u.username Faker::Name.name
    u.title Faker::Name.title
    u.password "hellohello"
    u.password_confirmation "hellohello"
 end
end
```

> Here is the mode spec model/user_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do

  user = ''
  describe "create" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end
  #describe "validations"
  describe "Count all the user" do
    it "should have one item created before being created" do
      #binding.pry
      expect(User.all.count).to eq(1)
    end
 end
end
```

When testing the model user_spec.rb model it gives the error:
[image]

Comment: Please add `u.password_confirmation "hellohello"` into `Factories/user.rb`.

Comment: Yes i have added u.password_confirmation "hellohello" but still has same issue.

Comment: Your code needs to go in the question as *text*, not as screenshots.

Comment: @AqibHameed: Please refer this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25068869/factorygirl-faker-same-data-being-generated-for-every-object-in-db-seed-data

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
u.first_name Faker::Name.first_name
u.last_name Faker::Name.last_name
u.email Faker::Internet.email
u.username Faker::Name.name
u.title Faker::Name.title
```

To this:

```
u.first_name {Faker::Name.first_name}
u.last_name {Faker::Name.last_name}
u.email {Faker::Internet.email}
u.username {Faker::Name.name}
u.title {Faker::Name.title}
```

This will cause Ruby to reevaluate the calls to Faker each time, generating various values each time.

Note that there is still the possibility for collisions, as Faker::email could generate the same email each time. I'd suggest using a sequence instead for fields with unique constraints. Something like this:

```
   sequence(:email) { |n| "person#{n}@example.com" }
   sequence(:username, 1000) { |n| "user#{n}" }
```

Comment: I use sequence instead of faker i got the same issue
Failure/Error:
       def initialize
         @example = nil
       end

     **ArgumentError:wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)**